remote-ssh: I use the jumpmachine so as to use the targetmachine, but meet some questions, could anyone help me?
Use the 202 as the jumpmachine,and 192 is the targetmachine，I added the following to the.config file：
Host 202...*
HostName 202...*
User jump
Port 22

Host 1921via202
HostName 192...*
User target
Port 22
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p 202...*

errors are the following:
[09:55:03.284] Log Level: 2
[09:55:03.296] SSH Resolver called for “ssh-remote+1921via202”, attempt 1
[09:55:03.297] “remote.SSH.useLocalServer”: false
[09:55:03.297] “remote.SSH.useExecServer”: true
[09:55:03.301] “remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal”: false
[09:55:03.301] “remote.SSH.remotePlatform”: {“202.117.43.4”:“linux”,“192...":“linux”,"202...”:“linux”,“192...*”:“linux”,“JumpMachine”:“linux”,“ubuntu”:“linux”}
[09:55:03.301] “remote.SSH.path”: undefined
[09:55:03.302] “remote.SSH.configFile”: C:\Users\hdl.ssh\config
[09:55:03.302] “remote.SSH.useFlock”: true
[09:55:03.302] “remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp”: false
[09:55:03.302] “remote.SSH.localServerDownload”: auto
[09:55:03.302] “remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket”: false
[09:55:03.302] “remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal”: false
[09:55:03.303] “remote.SSH.defaultExtensions”: 
[09:55:03.303] “remote.SSH.loglevel”: 2
[09:55:03.303] “remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding”: true
[09:55:03.303] “remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand”: false
[09:55:03.304] “remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange”: {}
[09:55:03.304] “remote.SSH.serverInstallPath”: {}
[09:55:03.321] VS Code version: 1.92.1
[09:55:03.321] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.111.2024040515
[09:55:03.322] win32 x64
[09:55:03.327] SSH Resolver called for host: 1921via202
[09:55:03.327] Setting up SSH remote “1921via202”
[09:55:03.333] Using commit id “eaa41d57266683296de7d118f574d0c2652e1fc4” and quality “stable” for server
[09:55:03.336] Install and start server if needed
[09:55:05.459] Checking ssh with “C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe -V”
[09:55:05.464] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:55:05.465] Checking ssh with “D:\texlive\texlive\2021\bin\win32\ssh.exe -V”
[09:55:05.467] Got error from ssh: spawn D:\texlive\texlive\2021\bin\win32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:55:05.467] Checking ssh with “C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V”
[09:55:05.470] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:55:05.471] Checking ssh with “C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V”
[09:55:05.474] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:55:05.474] Checking ssh with “C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V”
[09:55:05.476] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:55:05.476] Checking ssh with “C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V”
[09:55:05.478] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[09:55:05.478] Checking ssh with “C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V”
[09:55:05.535] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[09:55:05.541] Using SSH config file “C:\Users\hdl.ssh\config”
[09:55:05.542] Running script with connection command: “C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe” -T -D 64931 -F “C:\Users\hdl.ssh\config” 1921via202 bash
[09:55:05.544] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[09:55:05.867] > e]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exea
[09:55:05.868] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[09:55:05.903] > Bad owner or permissions on C:\Users\hdl/.ssh/config
[09:55:05.929] > kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[09:55:07.189] “install” terminal command done
[09:55:07.190] Install terminal quit with output: 过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[09:55:07.190] Received install output: 过程试图写入的管道不存在。
[09:55:07.191] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[09:55:07.193] Resolver error: Error:
at g.Create (c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:499181)
at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:496503)
at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:620043)
at async c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:579901
at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:583207)
at async k (c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:576866)
at async t.resolve (c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:580578)
at async c:\Users\hdl.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.111.2024040515\out\extension.js:2:846696
[09:55:07.201] ------

I tried changing the permissions for .config and adding absolute paths to the Settings, but without success. Now, I think it may have something to do with the difference between MAC and Android. I am very troubled by this problem. I read a lot of posts, but it doesn't solve the problem. Could anyone help me, thanks a lot.

If you are still getting that "Bad owner or permissions", then follow the instructions here: openssh windows bad owner or permissions
You need to set the permissions of the .ssh folder as instructed.
After that, try again and update the output on the post, if you still can't get it to work, then we can review.

I have solved my problem, thank you very much. I successfully solved the problem by correctly modifying the config file permission of.ssh, thank you.
